# Concat files using pandas python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, concatenation

I want to merge two files with same header but somehow it delivers the wrong dataframes.

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_excel ('01.xlsx')
df2=pd.read_excel ('02.xlsx')

frames=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)

frames.to_excel('new.xlsx')
```

df1 and df2 looks like :

[image: dataframes.png]

but result shows in another way like :

[image: new.xlsx.png]

I tried with `axis=1` so data fit with header but the it looks like duplicate header.

Comment: Did you try `print(frame.head())` before saving the excel file, to make sure you are reading correctly?

Comment: if i use axis=0,  2 data frames combined to 1 but the order of header is not kept.

Comment: @brianvu the `.concat()` method you are using is a reasonable solution. Without the actual data in the Excel spreadsheets, it is hard to identify the root cause. I would `print(df1)` and `print(df2)` to ensure that `pandas.read_excel()` function is correctly reading in the data initially.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the `header=None` parameter. Have you tried without it?

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('01.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('02.xlsx')
frames = pd.concat([df1, df2])
frames.head() # check result

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('new.xlsx')
frames.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

This works for me. The reason is that if `header=None` is set, Pandas treats the first row as any other row containing data rather than a special column-header row. It will therefore be repeated in your concatenated data frame.

Comment: This didnt work for me. Without header=None, the order of header is changed